# Async Parallel duplicate entries

Tags: arrays, node.js, asynchronous, firebase

So I am going through an array called `candidates` and performing certain tasks using each item in the array and then at the end pushing results to Firebase `candfb` . Here's the code:

```
    var candidates = json.stageCandidates.candidate;
    var list = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        var candidate = [];
        var id = candidates[i].candidateId;
        async.parallel([
            function(callback) {
                votesmart.getDetailedBio(id, function(err, json) {
                    if (!err && json.bio != undefined)
                        candidate.bio = json.bio;
                    callback();
                });
            },
            function(callback) {
                votesmart.getAddress(id, function(err, json) {
                    if (!err && json.address != undefined)
                        candidate.address = json.address.office[0];
                    callback();
                });
            },
            function(callback) {
                votesmart.getRating(id, function(err, json) {
                    if (!err && json.candidateRating != undefined)
                        candidate.ratings = json.candidateRating;
                    callback();
                });
            },
            function(callback) {
                votesmart.getVotes(id, function(err, json) {
                    if (!err && json.bills != undefined)
                        candidate.votes = json.bills;
                    callback();
                })
            },
            function(callback) {
                votesmart.getStances(id, function(err, json) {
                    if (!err && json.npat != undefined)
                        candidate.stances = json.npat;
                    callback();
                })
            }
        ], function() {
            candfb.push(candidate);
            // res.send(candidate);
        })
    };
```

Now the problem is that even though there are exactly 20 items being pushed (hardcoded in the loop) there are duplicates of some items and some are being skipped. Some items might be unique while others may have as much as 3 copies being pushed to Firebase. I've also checked and the array `candidates` does not have duplicates.

I suspect it might be due to me using `async.parallel()` but I'm unsure as to what to change to make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, it should fix your issue. It's a common mistake when mixing synchronous for loops with asynchronous calls. You need to close over i, otherwise it will be mutated.

```
  var candidates = json.stageCandidates.candidate;
    var list = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        (function(i){
            var candidate = [];
            var id = candidates[i].candidateId;
            async.parallel([
                function(callback) {
                    votesmart.getDetailedBio(id, function(err, json) {
                        if (!err && json.bio != undefined)
                            candidate.bio = json.bio;
                        callback();
                    });
                },
                function(callback) {
                    votesmart.getAddress(id, function(err, json) {
                        if (!err && json.address != undefined)
                            candidate.address = json.address.office[0];
                        callback();
                    });
                },
                function(callback) {
                    votesmart.getRating(id, function(err, json) {
                        if (!err && json.candidateRating != undefined)
                            candidate.ratings = json.candidateRating;
                        callback();
                    });
                },
                function(callback) {
                    votesmart.getVotes(id, function(err, json) {
                        if (!err && json.bills != undefined)
                            candidate.votes = json.bills;
                        callback();
                    })
                },
                function(callback) {
                    votesmart.getStances(id, function(err, json) {
                        if (!err && json.npat != undefined)
                            candidate.stances = json.npat;
                        callback();
                    })
                }
            ], function() {
                candfb.push(candidate);
                // res.send(candidate);
            })
        })(i)
    };
```